# How to set starting value in Observable with intervals

Tags: signalr, system.reactive, rx.net

I'm trying to make a subscription Hub with starting value. I cant set the starting value.

Now i have observable which generates DateTime.UtcNow in every 30 minutes interval.

```
public async Task Subscribe()
{
    var client = Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId);
    var subscription = new CompositeDisposable();
    var dateTimeUTCNow = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
           .Subscribe(@event => 
           {
               client.SendAsync("newDateTimeUtc", DateTime.UtcNow);
           });

    subscription.Add(dateTimeUTCNow);
    RegisterHandler(subscription, userFound.UserToken);
}
```

I must to set starting value - DateTime.NowUtc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the [StartWith](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html) operator?

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
    .Select(_ => DateTime.UtcNow)
    .StartWith(DateTime.UtcNow)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.Timer(TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period)` overload, instead of the Interval operator.
If you set dueTime to `TimeSpan.Zero` it will emit the first item at subscription time.

```cs
Observable
    .Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
    .Select(_ => DateTime.UtcNow)
    ...
```

As [gitbox mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57210201/6579063) you can also use StartWith. However StartWith will give you the declaration time instead of subscription time. If declaration time and subscription time are the same, there will of course be no difference.